# how to add to a map <int, list <int> >

Tags: c++, list, dictionary

Say I have a text file like so:

```
1 2
1 3
2 7
2 8
```

What I would like to do is to put these in a map of linked lists. So I have initialized a map like so, `map <int, list<int> > myMap;`

My problem is that I do not know how to add this to the list. Normally, we can add to the map by just having `myMap[someKey] = someValue;`
I'm having trouble adding a value to the list.

What I would like is to check whether the first int that is read is in the map, if not, create that entry, and add the second int to the list that corresponds to that key. For instance, if correctly done, line 1 should have inserted a key of 1 and a linked list with the element of 2. 
If the map already has that key, then the second int of that line should just be added to its linked list. For instance, line 2 should only be adding the element 3 to the 1's linked list.

What I'm hoping for is this:

```
key : value 
1 : 2 -> 3
2 : 7 -> 8
```

Here's my code:

```
ifstream infile;
infile.open(fname.c_str());
string line = "";
if (infile){
    while (getline(infile, line)){
       istringstream iss(line);
       int tail;
       iss >> tail;
       int edges;
       if (vertices.find(tail) == vertices.end()){
           iss >> edges;
           vertices[tail] = vertices[tail].push_back(edges);
           //I'm getting this error: no viable overloaded '='
       }
       else{
           iss >> edges;
           vertices[tail].push_back(edges);
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're getting an error because `push_back` is a `void` function, it doesn't return the list. So you can't assign it to `vertices[tail]`.

Comment: To understand the error message, you need to break the line down a bit `vertices[tail] = X` and `X = vertices[tail].push_back(edges);`. The second piece looks up a list, and calls the `push_back` method. Push_back returns `void` so the type of `X` is `void`. `vertices[tail] = X` requires X to be of type `list<int>`. `void` is not `list<int>`.

Comment: You need to think outside the box a bit. The `=` is a full-on assignment to the element, for simpler cases. You don't want that here. Your element is a list and you want to do `.push_back` on it. So just do `.push_back` — no `=` at all! You wouldn't use `=` to perform `.push_back` on some random list outside of a map. Don't be afraid to remove code from the simpler examples you're used to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you've read your two values from the file, this is all you need:

```
vertices[tail].push_back(edges);
```

This will do exactly what you are trying to do. `vertices[tail]` will return a reference to the list at that map location. If the list doesn't exist yet, one will be default constructed there. There is no need to check if it already existed, since `operator[]`  will do that anyway.

Comment: so then it seems that I wouldn't need an if else here? I can just write `vertices[tail].push_back(edges)`?